# cannot import a module after os.chdir()

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have a python file with the class `A` defined in it in a different directory than the one I am working in. I want to import a module from that class in my script. I wrote something like this in jupyter:

```
import os
parent_dir = 'path/to/class'
os.chdir(parent_dir) 
from A import a
```

It works perfectly fine and I get to execute the program. However when I run the script in the same directory from the terminal, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

I put a `os.getcwd()` before the error to make sure it is in the same directory, and when I go to that directory from the terminal and import the module directly there are no errors. I wonder why I get this error when running the script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use `os.chdir`, because it changes a global state, that can lead to unexpected behaviour somewhere else.

Expand `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/module')
```

Comment: it's better to do `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'path/to/module')`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I did have this version, but not sure, if the OP uses paths relative to the script file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `from path.to.class import className`