# Why can't I import a module in a Python script, but I can import it in a REPL?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is that this code does not work (run with `python3 x.py`):

```
import os
os.chdir("/app/my-favorite-module")
from my_favorite_module.foo import Bar
os.chdir("/app")
```

(says no module called my_favorite_module`)

but using the Python REPL works (launched in the same directory as the script):

```
root@afad0fa67aa8:/content# python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os; os.chdir("/app/my-favorite-module")
>>> from my_favorite_module.foo import Bar
>>> os.chdir("/app")
```

I found a workaround using `sys.path`, but I'm curious about the underlying reason.

Comment: Not sure `chdir` will shift the include path when run as a script.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279818/4935162)

Comment: It would be messy security-wise if `os.chdir` changed `sys.path` for scripts for the same reason that reasonable (non-Microsoft) people haven't added `.` to `PATH` for roughly four decades now. Inadvertently loading code from somewhere you didn't intentionally choose to trust is a Bad Thing.

Comment: The module search path is fixed when the script starts.  I don't believe that calling `os.chdir()` has any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to how the Python import system and module search paths work.

In the script version:

```
import os
os.chdir("/app/my-favorite-module")
from my_favorite_module.foo import Bar
os.chdir("/app")
```

When you change the current working directory using `os.chdir`, it only affects the script's current process and its child processes (if any). When the script is importing the module `my_favorite_module.foo`, Python searches for the module in the standard module search paths. Since you changed the working directory, the current directory is `/app/my-favorite-module`, and Python won't look in this directory for modules. Instead, it will look in the standard module paths, and thus, it will not find `my_favorite_module.foo`.

On the other hand, in the Python REPL version:

```
import os; os.chdir("/app/my-favorite-module")
from my_favorite_module.foo import Bar
os.chdir("/app")
```

The Python REPL runs interactively, and when you change the current working directory using `os.chdir` in the REPL, it affects the Python process running the REPL itself. As a result, when you then import `my_favorite_module.foo`, Python will search for the module in the current directory (`/app/my-favorite-module`), find it, and import it successfully.

As you've mentioned, using `sys.path` is a proper workaround for this situation. By adding the directory to `sys.path`, you are essentially telling Python to look in that directory when searching for modules, and this works consistently both in scripts and the Python REPL.